# Разработка расширения для chrome

Tags: chrome-extension, extension

В конфигурации manifest.json, объект permissions, в него записываются url на которых будет работать расширение. есть адрес - 'site.com', 'site.ua', 'site.ru'. Для удобства делаю вот так - `*://site.com/*`. Как сделать так что бы не прописывать конкретную доменную зону? На пример: `*://site.*/*`, но к сожалению это не работает (данный пример).

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации знак * и ???](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) допустим только в начале. Поэтому сделать желаемое у вас не получится. Можно только вписать все доменные зоны по порядку. Как советуют на EnSO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163102/how-to-make-chrome-extension-work-on-all-domain-zones-of-specific-site) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613731/chrome-extension-run-on-all-google-domains-and-a-specific-page) можно сгенерировать кодом.

1. Перейти на http://www.google.com/supported_domains
2. Открыть консоль браузера и выполнить код (к примеру для translate):

   ```
   copy(document.body.innerText.split(" ").map((item) => { return `*://translate${item}/*` }))
   ```
3. Скопировать полученный результат себе в манифест.

---

Ну или активировать расширение и дальше уже из самого JS проверять хост, если есть такая возможность.

---

Еще по второй ссылке EnSO можете посмотреть в сторону использования include_globs